# Passing passwords between activities

Tags: android, security, encryption

Is it safe to pass a password from one activity to another without encrypting it? I will then, once it's in the next activity, encrypt it and store it. Or should I encrypt it first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you stay within your own app (not other apps, this is fishier), there shouldn't be a problem with this.  The reason is that your information stays within your process, so others are never seeing it.  If you pass an unencrypted password across a process boundary, that's probably a bad idea.  There's a paper on this [1] that might be worth a read (I don't think it's too harsh, even for "real programmers").  In general, as long as you keep data within your app, you should be safe, simply because of the sandboxing that the underlying Linux implementation provides for you.

[1]  Analyzing Inter-Application Communication in Android
www.sigmobile.org/mobisys/2011/slides/interapp.pdf

Comment: Cool. thats what i was thinking. And yes, it'll stay with in my own app.

Answer (score -1):

you used put extra and my code below:

```
addencPass = username + ":" + password;
        encPass = Base64.encodeToString(addencPass.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT
                | Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP);
```